# Bash script to filter JSON text

Tags: json, bash, shell, jq, data-extraction

I have the following JSON File:

```
{
  "error": 0,
  "data": {
    "0": {
      "orderid": "40007600",
      "price": "9.99",
      "listingname": "iPhone 8",
      "smallphoto": "https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51b5iaLTjgL._SL160_.jpg",
      "photo": "https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51b5iaLTjgL.jpg"
    },
    "1": {
      "orderid": "40007598",
      "price": "9.99",
      "listingname": "iPhone 8 Plus",
      "smallphoto": "https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51CVLqsSNkL._SL160_.jpg",
      "photo": "https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51CVLqsSNkL.jpg"
    },
    "4": {
      "orderid": "40007595",
      "price": "9.39",
      "listingname": "Nadelflaschen",
      "smallphoto": "https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41OHDP2rAeL._SL160_.jpg",
      "photo": "https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41OHDP2rAeL.jpg"
    },
  }
}
```

How can I filter everything with a bash script, so I get all image URLs of "smallphoto" into a text file?

f.e. [https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41OHDP2rAeL.*SL160*.jpg](https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41OHDP2rAeL._SL160_.jpg) from "Nadelflaschen"

I tried awk and jq commands. But I am just to dump to understand the jq syntax.

awk is possible, but I only get unfiltered links with backslashes, which do not work.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately this is neither a tutorial site nor web search replacement. We can help solve [certain problems](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), but it's **your** job to [put some efforts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) in the first place, incl. elementary [(re)search](https://google.com/). Majority of newbies' questions are not unique and has already been answered multiple times.

Answer (score 4):

```
jq '.data[] | .smallphoto' input.json
```

yields:

```
"https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51b5iaLTjgL._SL160_.jpg"
"https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51CVLqsSNkL._SL160_.jpg"
"https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41OHDP2rAeL._SL160_.jpg"
```

The key point here is that `.[]` (`.data[]` being an abbreviated form of `.data|.[]`) can be used with JSON objects, not just arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another filter which will find `.smallphoto` no matter how deeply nested:

```
.. | .smallphoto?//empty
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tZBBS8MwGIbv@xWh5zVNtZ3rLiJ6UCizMPE6Yhvb1DTJkhRRt79uTbZpB@oOUg@BPN8b3nw89ap7GwHgEaWE8mYAjR0V2GALLrGEvq4WhCqIooUdeRFC6GyCkDf@DKWiOXFRApOkHzOqDeUlx802pFklOAHT/oFuMGOyEka4vDJG6lkQ0AaXRPukhVozf0@4wa@Cw1w0@zy4CeLwIaY4vavLFC4XaThBS1jL8mCvQapd5bZxsyv2wmNi4mT6VzEgY60e0M7lfbrSi/nTP9jpq7/ZiY7biX@0c/q7nTkuCHtkWOcV4YPZicLb66vsRF2Qwe0cVvd2Ru5s1h2EYA375c9BEJBGmpeuexfSUMF15/u8ZfYLLltjQeFnX7TGwgc)

Sample Run (assumes corrected sample data in `data.json`)

```
$ jq -M '.. | .smallphoto?//empty' data.json
"https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51b5iaLTjgL._SL160_.jpg"
"https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51CVLqsSNkL._SL160_.jpg"
"https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41OHDP2rAeL._SL160_.jpg"
```